# tabBar and navigationBar size strange return value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new iOS dev.

I'm calling following in viewDidLoad

```
CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat navigationBarHegith = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
```

The return values are 0 for both, why this is so ? Doesn't it mean that navigationBar and tabBar are already loaded into memory and initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` doesn't guarantee that user interface objects have been instantiated - they're zero because they probably don't exist. Try `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely that your view controller does not have tab bar controller and navigation controller.

Check the value of self.tabBarController and self.navigationController and if they are nil (zero), unlike java or C++, invoke method on nil will simply just return 0, which is what you got.

Comment: Your right, ! The structure is following, in app delegate I've created tabBarViewControllers with UINavigation Controller, so are they accessible by self ?

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me. make shure, that your tab bar and nav. bar are allready inited, when you  aske there properties. Do it in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method.